# I really cant understand an error occurring just due to the difference in writing the Function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void minmax(int,int,int*,int*);
int main()
{
    int a[]={186,35,132,745,2345,23,154,36,24,2,55,26,346,2456,224,257,244,2784,032,234,2134};
    int len,min,max;
    len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    minmax(a,len,&min,&max);
    printf("Largest: %d and Smallest: %d ",max,min);
    return 0;
}
void minmax(int arr[],int len,int *min, int *max)
{
    *min=*max=arr[0];
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>*max)
        {
            *max=arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i]<*min)
        {
            *min=arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

While writing this code I get the following errors
**..\src\Test6.c: In function 'main':

..\src\Test6.c:8:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'minmax' makes integer from pointer without a cast

..\src\Test6.c:2:6: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'

..\src\Test6.c: At top level:

..\src\Test6.c:12:6: error: conflicting types for 'minmax'

..\src\Test6.c:2:6: note: previous declaration of 'minmax' was here**

But when I change the whole code by declaring and defining the function initially everything works so smooth.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void minmax(int arr[],int len,int *min, int *max)
{
    *min=*max=arr[0];
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>*max)
        {
            *max=arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i]<*min)
        {
            *min=arr[i];
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a[]={186,35,132,745,2345,23,154,36,24,2,55,26,346,2456,224,257,244,2784,032,234,2134};
    int len,min,max;
    len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    minmax(a,len,&min,&max);
    printf("Largest: %d and Smallest: %d ",max,min);
    return 0;
}
```

**Please help me understand the concept or error that I am missing...**

Comment: Integer constants starting with `0` in C are octal format, so `032` gives the decimal number 26. Is this intentionally?

Comment: the error says all the reason right ?, its kind of self explanatory right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version :

> ```
> void minmax(int,int,int*,int*);
> ```

then

> ```
> void minmax(int arr[],int len,int *min, int *max)
> {
> ```

the declaration is not compatible with the definition, nor with that use in *main* :

> ```
> minmax(a,len,&min,&max);
> ```

where *a* it a `int *` (similar to `int[]`)

Just modify the declaration to have :

```
 void minmax(int[],int,int*,int*);
```

---

In your second version *minmax* is defined before to be used by *main* so there is no wrong declaration

Comment: Could you then please help me like what change to it can make it right? I really am not getting why isnt it compatible.

Comment: Thanks now I understood what I was missing. Its working fine now! :))

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void minmax(int*,int,int*,int*);   //just change int to int*
int main()
{
    int a[]={186,35,132,745,2345,23,154,36,24,2,55,26,346,2456,224,257,244,2784,032,234,2134};
    int len,min,max;
    len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    minmax(a,len,&min,&max);
    printf("Largest: %d and Smallest: %d ",max,min);
    return 0;
}
void minmax(int arr[],int len,int *min, int *max)
{
    *min=*max=arr[0];
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>*max)
        {
            *max=arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i]<*min)
        {
            *min=arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.